# ZXing double image/overlay after scan

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I am using the ZXing library, fully integrated with jar files, in my Android app and have the following problem:

**Problem:**

After scanning a barcode, the scanned image stays on top on the live camera feed at about 50% transparency for about 1-2 seconds.

**Question:**

Is there any way to have just the scanned image appear at 0% transparency, instead of the strange overlay? Or, even better, can it show a custom fragment?

Thank you.

**Code: [w/o unrelated parts]**

```
public static void initiateScan(Fragment fragment) {
    IntentIntegrator ii = new IntentIntegrator(fragment);
    DisplayMetrics dm = fragment.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    ii.addExtra("SCAN_WIDTH", dm.heightPixels);
    ii.addExtra("SCAN_HEIGHT", dm.widthPixels / 4);
    ii.addExtra("SCAN_MODE", "ONE_D_MODE");

    List<String> c = new ArrayList<String>();
    c.add("CODE_39");

    ii.initiateScan(c, -1);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE) { // scan from ZXing
        String raw_vin=null;
        String vin = null;
        boolean success=false;

        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, 
                                resultCode, data);
        if(result!=null)
        {
            String content = result.getContents();
            if(content!=null)
            {
                raw_vin=content;
                vin=raw_vin;
                success=true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Example:**

[image: Example of double image]

Comment: if you are using zxing with source code you can customize according to your requirement

Comment: @Pavan Any suggestions or hints as to where this would be located? Any idea as to what would need to change, if at all possible?

Comment: here is the source code you had to find which activity or view you want to customize https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Comment: @Pavan uhh, thanks for the link to the source code? Not really what I meant when I asked for hints ... I meant hints as to how to modify the source code and where.

Comment: for that you have to go through the code and check which class contains same for example just check the class which first called from your app to zxing then you have check further processing

Comment: @Dima can you provide a screenshot of what is happening. I use ZXing and have never run into the issue you are describing.

Comment: @srayhunter I added a screenshot. Thank you.

Comment: could you share your code , specially the onCreate and onActivityResult method of your active ?

Comment: @shuvro I added some code that deals with ZXing. onCreate does nothing with ZXing; I tried commenting out everything in it without luck (aka, same problem). Thank you.

Comment: I haven't seen anything wrong .  Only thing I can say , you can add this library using gradle dependency .  And using a  separate activity for capturing .

Comment: The gradle dependencies are 
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'

Comment: @shuvro Thank you; I'll give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: ok , I will wait for your response

Comment: @shuvro still no luck; same problem.

Comment: sorry to hear that , I can share my approach . https://github.com/sshuvro58/BarCodeScanner/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have in the **build.gradle** file for dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.3@aar'
```

Try this in the **initiateScan** method:

```
public static void initiateScan(Fragment fragment) {
    IntentIntegrator ii = IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(fragment);
    DisplayMetrics dm = fragment.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    ii.addExtra("SCAN_WIDTH", dm.heightPixels);
    ii.addExtra("SCAN_HEIGHT", dm.widthPixels / 4);
    ii.addExtra("SCAN_MODE", "ONE_D_MODE");
    ii.initiateScan(Collections.singletonList("CODE_39"));
}
```

Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: This ended up working; thank you. Just as a side note for others, I think SCAN_MODE, SCAN_WIDTH, SCAN_HEIGHT are not supported with journeyapps.

Comment: @Dima you are probably right. I did a small search and could not find them, but left them there since I did not fully test those out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to explain why this problem happen, but I am using ZXing for my barcode scanner application without 50% transparent as you. The following is my solution:

**Layout:**

```
<com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView
    android:id="@+id/barcode_scanner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp">

</com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView>
```

**In fragment:**

```
private CompoundBarcodeView barcodeView;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webservice_layout, container, false);

        barcodeView = (CompoundBarcodeView) v.findViewById(R.id.barcode_scanner);

        barcodeView.decodeContinuous(callback);
......
}
```

**Callback function:**

```
private BarcodeCallback callback = new BarcodeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void barcodeResult(BarcodeResult result) {

            if (SOAP_ACTION.equals("") || SOAP_METHOD.equals("") || soapProperty.equals("")) {
                barcodeView.pause();
            } else {
                if (result.getText() != null) {
                    barcodeView.setStatusText(result.getText());

                    barcodeView.pause();

                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            barcodeView.resume();
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        }
};
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

My approach is the following:

```
//start the scanning
public void startQRCodeScanning() {
    IntentIntegrator integrator = IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this);
    integrator.setCaptureActivity(ScanActivity);
    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
    integrator.setOrientationLocked(true);
    integrator.initiateScan();
}

//onActivityResult:
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null) {
        if (result.getContents() == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Cancelled scan");
            //we want to finish the current activity
            //as it does not make sense to do anything else
            finishActivity();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Scanned " + result.getContents());
            setConnectionString(result.getContents());
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

//next I have the QRCodeScanningActivity

    public class QRCodeScannerActivity extends Activity {

    private CaptureManager capture;
    private CompoundBarcodeView barcodeScannerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_scanner);

        if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP, ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);
        }

        barcodeScannerView = (CompoundBarcodeView)findViewById(R.id.zxing_barcode_scanner);

        capture = new CaptureManager(this, barcodeScannerView);
        capture.initializeFromIntent(getIntent(), savedInstanceState);
        capture.decode();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        capture.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        capture.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        capture.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        capture.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return barcodeScannerView.onKeyDown(keyCode, event) || super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
 }

 //Next you need to define the layouts and everything.
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black">

    <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView
            android:id="@+id/zxing_barcode_scanner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:zxing_scanner_layout="@layout/barcode_scanner_layout"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```